# Trim Oracle String and Add Dashes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an 18 character string field needs the 1st 5 characters removed and then dashes added after the 11th and 15th segments. Is there a way to do this with 1 update?

```
000003061114150000
```

to

```
306111-4150-000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple `SUBSTR` concatenation does the job:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '000003061114150000' from dual)
  3  select
  4    substr(col, 6, 6)  ||'-'||
  5    substr(col, 12, 4) ||'-'||
  6    substr(col, 16) result
  7  from test;

RESULT
---------------
306111-4150-000

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to one line select statement

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(
        LTRIM('000003061114150000', 10),
        1,
        6
    )|| '-' || SUBSTR(
        LTRIM('000003061114150000', 10),
        7,
        4
    )|| '-' || SUBSTR(
        LTRIM('000003061114150000', 10),
        11
    )
FROM
    dual;
```

Result

```
306111-4150-000
```